# enable PUT on IIS 6 for wcf .net 4.0 "SVCless" rest services

Tags: wcf, iis-6

How do I enable PUT on my IIS 6 for wcf .net 4.0 "SVCless" rest services. 
My Services are at the root of the website.

Please help!

TIA

EDIT:

I get "501 - Not Implemented" when the service is hosted at the root of the site. If if it is a child application it works.

Comment: Did you already configured wildcard mapping? Is HTTP GET and POST working?

Comment: Yes it is! Also PUT works fine when it is a sub application. 

PUT works when it is hosted at

server/Version1/Service

but if i move it to 
server/Service
 then it does work.i get "501 - Not Implemented"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to enable Webdav

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this.

- Go to IIS MMC
- Go to properties of hosting site
- Go to Home directory tab
- Go to configuration
- Check that wildcard mapping is configured
- Check that application extensions maps aspnet_isapi.dll (from .NET 4.0) to all verbs - default is only GET, POST, HEAD, DEBUG

Comment: My web service does not have any extentions so i don't think changing those settings would help.
What would have been great is if i could specify Verbs for wild card mapping.